# How to break connections TCP/IP by keepalive postgreSQL without changing anything in the register?

Tags: .net, postgresql, tcp, keep-alive

I have a system working with the client-server structure and PostgreSQL 8.4. 
My problem is that if a client is editing a record and lose his connection to the server, the TCPIP connection is still considered! So, the record stay allocated for the client in my database. 
I need the records to be free for edit in a few minutes. Therefore I set the KEEPALIVE configuration in my "postgresql.conf":

```
tcp_keepalives_idle = 60 # TCP_KEEPIDLE, in seconds; 
tcp_keepalives_interval = 60 # TCP_KEEPINTVL, in seconds; 
tcp_keepalives_count  = 5 # TCP_KEEPCNT
```

After making these settings and restart the server the system continues to function the same way: Just breaks the connection TCPIP after two hours and then deallocates the records in PostgreSQL. I need an efficient and safe way for the PostgreSQL to understand that it has to break these connections as configured!

Comment: What's your client and server operating systems and which versions? Maybe your system does not support keepalives or changing keepalive parameters. Is it any message in Postgres log about KEEP-something failed or not supported?

Comment: Tometzky: My OS is Windows Server 2008!

Comment: Tometzky: Now, I'm testing in a Windows 7 and the log says: "2010-07-29 08:17:34 BRT LOG:  sistema de banco de dados está pronto para aceitar conexões
2010-07-29 08:17:34 BRT LOG:  inicializador do autovacuum foi iniciado
2010-07-29 08:17:35 BRT LOG:  setsockopt(TCP_KEEPIDLE) not supported
2010-07-29 08:17:35 BRT LOG:  setsockopt(TCP_KEEPINTVL) not supported
2010-07-29 08:17:35 BRT LOG:  setsockopt(TCP_KEEPCNT) not supported"

Comment: Tometzky, I'm very disappointed with PostgreSQL! I need to break idle connections! There any way to identify and break lost connections without the use keepalive? Something like 'Notify' for example? My msn kanandasilvanos@hotmail.com. Thanks

Comment: I've added a code, which should work when added to Pg source. You'd need to patch and rebuild Pg for yourself if using system-wide settings isn't possible.

Comment: Tometzky, thanks, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL on Windows does not support keepalive settings for one connection. It is using `setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE, ...)` which is IMHO Linux-specific.

You can implement a patch for Postgres so it uses [`SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877220%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Something like this in `src/backend/libpq/pqcomm.c` in `StreamConnection` function.

```
{
    DWORD bytesReturned = 0;
    tcp_keepalive vals;
    vals.keepalivetime = 60*1000; /* milliseconds */
    vals.keepaliveinterval = 60*1000; /* milliseconds */
    vals.onoff = 1;
    err = WSAIoctl(
        port->sock,
        SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS,
        (char *)&vals, sizeof(vals), NULL, 0,
        &bytesReturned, NULL, NULL);
    if (err == -1) {
        elog(LOG, "WSAIoctl(SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS) failed: %m");
    }
}
```

Or you can set system-wide settings in Windows registry `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters` using [KeepAliveInterval](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758083%28WS.10%29.aspx) and [KeepAliveTime](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782936%28WS.10%29.aspx) settings (count is always 10 on Windows Vista and later).